# Error initializing task PropertyGroup: Not registered task PropertyGroup

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I've been developing an android application using Xamarin. It's been working great until today when I updated Xamarin and the Android-SDKs and all of a sudden I get the following error message:

"Error initializing task PropertyGroup: Not registered task PropertyGroup."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>10.0.0</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{BCE0722A-D10F-4FBA-8415-13FA2CCF2ED9}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>InspectAdminClientAndroid</RootNamespace>
    <MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>Resources</MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>
    <MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>Assets</MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>
    <AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
    <AndroidApplication>True</AndroidApplication>
    <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
    <AssemblyName>InspectAdminClientAndroid</AssemblyName>
    <AndroidManifest>Properties\AndroidManifest.xml</AndroidManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <ConsolePause>false</ConsolePause>
    <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <ConsolePause>false</ConsolePause>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>false</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android" />
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <HintPath>..\..\Downloads\Json50r6\Bin\Portable40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Resources\Resource.designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Activities\LoginActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Activities\CustomerAliasActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Activities\LoadSettingsActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Activities\LoadingObjectsActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Activities\ObjectListActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Activities\ObjectDetailsActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Activities\LoadingInspectionsActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Activities\InspectionListActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Activities\InspectionDetailsActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Activities\AboutActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Activities\ChooseUserActivity.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Resources\AboutResources.txt" />
    <None Include="Assets\AboutAssets.txt" />
    <None Include="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\Strings.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\Login.axml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\Colors.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\CustomerAlias.axml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\LoadingObjects.axml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\ObjectDetails.axml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\LoadingSettings.axml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\LoadingInspections.axml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\InspectionDetails.axml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\About.axml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\bg_property_description.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\bg_property_position_info.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\expandablegroup_gradient.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\expandablegroup_title_gradient.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\expandablegroup_vertical_gradient.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\ic_checkbox.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\ic_radio.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\login_background.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\slidingmenu_background.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\slidingmenu_item_background.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\slidingmenu_item_color.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\slidingmenu_item_subtext_color.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\slidingmenu_item_text_color.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\slidingmenu_shadows.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\upgrade_button_background.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_action_cancel.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_action_create_inspection.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_action_create_object.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_action_delete.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_action_details.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_action_done.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_action_done_holo_light.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_action_edit.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_action_get_position.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_action_messages.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_action_new_messages.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_action_object.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_action_refresh.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_checkbox_checked.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_checkbox_unchecked.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_coordinate.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_create_object.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_delete.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_edit.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_image.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_image_missing.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_inspection.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_inspection_list.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_list_finished.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_list_locked.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_list_new.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_list_not_locked.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_list_started.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_list_sync_on.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_list_synchronized.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_list_unsynchronized.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_logout.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_mandatory.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_mandatory_large.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_object.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_object_list.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_radio_checked.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_radio_unchecked.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_set_position.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-ldpi\ic_launcher.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_action_cancel.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_action_copy.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_action_create_inspection.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_action_create_object.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_action_delete.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_action_details.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_action_done.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_action_done_holo_light.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_action_edit.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_action_get_position.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_action_messages.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_action_new_messages.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_action_object.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_action_paste.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_action_refresh.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_action_user.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_checkbox_checked.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_checkbox_unchecked.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_coordinate.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_create_object.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_delete.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_edit.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_image.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_image_missing.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_inspection.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_inspection_list.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_launcher.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_list_finished.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_list_locked.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_list_new.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_list_not_locked.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_list_started.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_list_sync_on.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_list_synchronized.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_list_unsynchronized.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_logout.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_mandatory.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_mandatory_large.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_object.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_object_list.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_radio_checked.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_radio_unchecked.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_set_position.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_action_cancel.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_action_create_inspection.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_action_create_object.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_action_delete.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_action_details.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_action_done.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_action_done_holo_light.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_action_edit.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_action_get_position.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_action_messages.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_action_new_messages.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_action_object.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_action_refresh.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_checkbox_checked.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_checkbox_unchecked.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_coordinate.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_create_object.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_delete.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_edit.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_image.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_image_missing.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_inspection.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_inspection_list.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_list_finished.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_list_locked.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_list_new.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_list_started.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_list_sync_on.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_list_synchronized.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_list_unsynchronized.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_logout.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_mandatory.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_mandatory_large.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_object.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_object_list.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_radio_checked.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_radio_unchecked.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_set_position.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\login_header.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Novell\Novell.MonoDroid.CSharp.targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\InspectAdminClientCore\InspectAdminClientCore.csproj">
      <Project>{E37CD97C-F662-48C3-9978-2643BE699997}</Project>
      <Name>InspectAdminClientCore</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Core.Database\Core.Database.csproj">
      <Project>{61E35A5F-193A-4EC9-9530-1281EFA2363D}</Project>
      <Name>Core.Database</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Activities\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\Color\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable-ldpi\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a stack trace or screenshot or something that shows where you get the message?

Comment: It's when I try to compile the project. I probably should say that I reference Portable Libraries as well, don't know if that matters.

Comment: You can try link your files over in an Android Library Project and see if that solves the problem, PCL's work OK for me, however Reflection has some issues. Hence it should not be where the fault is. I think PropertyGroup refers to something in your csproj file, where you have items and propertygroups inside, could you post a screenshot of your error and post your csproj file here?

Comment: Csproj:
http://www.filedropper.com/inspectadminclientandroid

Screenshot:
http://www.filedropper.com/screenshot2013-07-29at111532am

Comment: What version of Mono do you have installed? According to this, you will need 3.2 installed to use the latest Xamarin.Android: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6394/error-initializing-task-property-group#latest

Comment: Aye, that seemed to have been the problem, lowered the mono version as a temporary fix for a bug in the new Xamarin update. Set the version to 3.2 and updated to the newest beta-version of Xamarin instead and alas it works! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Mono 3.2 (or later) since Xamarin.Android 4.8 uses a different compiler than the previous versions which requires Mono 3.2. (Creds goes to Cheesebaron)

Comment: I just want to add that if you have Mono 3.2 installed and it still doesn't work, you probably haven't enabled Mono 3.2 as the active runtime in Xamarin Studio. To do so simply go to the top menu:

`Project-> Active Runtime-> Mono 3.2 (or something higher)`